# Three.js load fbx file with Textures

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a fbx file with textures https://github.com/nxhoang/Three.js-Fxb-and-Textures/tree/master/models/fbx (S1615BA1019U_AK0018.fbx and myfile.fbx is saved by 3D app from S1615BA1019U_AK0018.fbx)

I tried to open file by three.js:

```
            var loader = new THREE.FBXLoader();
            loader.load('models/fbx/myfile.fbx', function(object) {
                scene.add(object);
            }, (ev) => {
                console.log(ev);
            }, (e) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
```

Refer: https://github.com/nxhoang/Three.js-Fxb-and-Textures/blob/master/webgl_loader_fbx_nurbs.html

Unfortunately, there are an error:

```
Error: THREE.FBXLoader: Unknown property type
```

I tried another fbx file then show me another error:

`ReferenceError: Zlib is not defined`

My expectation is opening the fbx file.

Answer (score 0):

I think THREE.FBXLoader requires inflate.js from Zlib, so try adding:

```
<script src="js/libs/inflate.min.js"></script>
```

to the head, before you load FBXLoader.js

Comment: That will quiet the zlib error, but it doesn't guarantee the model will render...